# python 3.3 Password checker

Tags: python

I am creating a program that checks passwords to see if they are strong enough:

- they need caps,
- lower case,
- numbers,
- symbols and
- cannot contain easy passwords.

As you can see below this is only some of my code and I have a menu, and a password checker, the only problem is that the checker doesn't seem to be working as when I enter a password, its always saying its a strong password even though it does not contain any caps or numbers or symbols. Below is my code so far.

```
import random #importing random
import time #importing time
global Menu

def Menu():
    global optionchoice #globalising variable optionchoice so that it can be used inside of another def of the code
    print("Hey, Welcome to PassWordChecker.")
    time.sleep(2) #delaying the next line for 2 seconds
    print("Please choose one of the options below." )
    time.sleep(1)
    print("MENU:")
    print("***")
    print("    press 1 once for              :           password checker  ")
    print("    press 2 twice for             :           password generator")
    print("    press 3 two or three times to :           Quit              ")
    print("                                                                 ***") #creating a basic menu
    optionchoice = (input("which option would you like to choose?"))

def checkpasswordandinput():
    global optionchoice
    optionchoice = optionchoice
    if optionchoice == '1':
        print(" please enter a password. ")
        UserPassword = input("")
        if len(UserPassword) <= 8 or len(UserPassword) >= 24 or UserPassword == UserPassword.isupper() or UserPassword == UserPassword.isdigit() or UserPassword == UserPassword.islower() or UserPassword == UserPassword.isalpha():
            print("make sure your password includes numbers and upper and lower case letters  ")
            UserPassword = input('please enter a new password')
        else:
            print('your password is a very good one that is difficult to crack')
            return Menu()
```

**Notes to future readers:**

Please do not write code in the form above:

1. Do not import modules you don't need
2. Do not use global variables
3. Do use loops: eg `while True:`
4. Do call functions from other functions
5. Do return values from one function back to the caller: `optionchoice = menu()`

The above code would have been better in this form:

```
import time

def menu():
    print("    press 1 for password checker  ")
    print("    press 2 for password generator")
    print("    press 3 to Quit")
    return input("which option would you like to choose?")

def checkpasswordandinput():
    while True:
        optionchoice = menu()
        if optionchoice == '1':
            #Enter password and validate
            pass
        # detect other options
        if optionchoice == '3':
            break


checkpasswordandinput()
```

Comment: This question is begging for the xkcd reference: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: `UserPassword == UserPassword.islower()` Those checks do not make sense. You are comparing a string to a boolean.

Comment: I tried running your code and nothing happened. Then I added a call to `Menu()` and `checkpasswordandinput()`, which I assume is in your real code, but you deleted it from the question for some reason. I tried entering the password "blah" and it correctly says "make sure your password includes numbers and upper and lower case letters". You say that your program always says that passwords are strong, but that's not what I'm seeing. Please provide an [mcve] that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: tobias_k okay but im wondering how i would make sure the password has some caps but not all caps, do you have any advice on how to do this? thanks

Comment: if the password and its lowercase version are not identical it has one or more caps symbols.

Comment: Kevin are you sure, ive just tried that now myself with the calls(which are in my real code) and it still appears to be saying that the password is good o matter what, however i will try again thank you

Comment: @Kevin i see, but the reason it corrects you is because its less that eight characters, try the password 'RRRRrrrr' which should be wrong because there are no numbers or symbols, and the program incorrectly says it is a good password

Answer (score 1):

Those checks in the form `UserPassword == UserPassword.isupper()` will not work. Here, you are comparing a string, the password, to a boolean, the result of `isX()`. Hence, all those checks are `False` and you get to the `else` branch (if the length is acceptable).

In the case of upper and lowercase chars, you could use `UserPassword == UserPassword.upper()`  instead (just `upper`, not `isupper`, and analogously with `lower()`), i.e. compare the password to it's upper/lowercased version, but for digits this does not work. Instead, you can use `any` to check if any char is a digit: `any(c.isdigit() for c in UserPassword)`

Edit: You can use `UserPassword == UserPassword.upper()` to check if the password does *not* contains any *lowercase* letters, which is kind of unintuitive. Instead, I'd suggest using `any` for all the checks and also inversing the condition so the "positive" case is in the `if`s body and the "negative" in the else. Something like this:

```
up = UserPassword
if 8 <= len(up) <= 24 and any(c.isupper() for c in up) and any(c.islower() for c in up) and any(c.isdigit() for c in up) and any(c.isalpha() for c in up):
```

Or a bit shorter, using a list of functions:

```
if 8 <= len(up) <= 24 and all(any(f(c) for c in up) for f in (str.islower, str.isupper, str.isdigit, str.isalpha)):
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do something like the following:

```
hasUpper = False
hasLower = False
hasDigit = False
```

etc etc

Then, go through the 'password' one character at a time:
ie. string[1], string[2], string[3]

Run your boolean result on it (isupper, islower, etc)
when true, change your hasUpper, hasLower, hasDigit to True

Then, once gone through the whole string, check your boolean results with your requirements.  ie:

if requirements are upper, lower, and digit.

```
if hasUpper = True and hasLower = True and hasDigit = True:
```

then it's a good password, etc.

Make sense?

Comment: Did you mean `if hasUpper == True ...`? (Or just `hasUpper`; the `== True` is redundant anyway)

Comment: Yeah - my apologies - either would work:

'if hasUpper' OR 

'if hasUpper == True'